# Controlling graphics card ArcMap uses

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, windows, arcgis-10.7, graphics-card

Is there a way to control the graphics card ArcMap 10.7 uses?

My Windows laptop has two graphics cards (stock AMD and NVIDIA GeForce). The default settings seamlessly switch between the two depending on program requirements, and I've never had any issues.

I just set up a docking station for my laptop so that I can have multiple extended monitors (Wavlink Universal Docking Station WL-US39DK1). It turns out that when my laptop lid is closed, the docking station gets locked-in on the basic graphics card (I've confirmed this in Wavlink's display manager) and I get the `Error: LoadLibrary failed with error 126: The specified module could not be found.` and of course ArcMap will not open. When the laptop lid is open, ArcMap loads fine and uses the NVIDIA graphics card. This is consistent with how
[ESRI Technical Support](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022927) describes the error.

My current workaround is to just disable my basic graphics card (in Windows Device Manager), as suggested in [various Google searches](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=NVIDIA+Card+Not+Active+When+Using+DisplayLink), which forces the laptop to always use the NVIDIA card. But I think this is slowing things down and producing some latency in other programs. I'd rather have access to my basic graphics card  *and* ArcMap while keeping my laptop lid closed. The only way I can think to acheive this is to force ArcMap to use the basic card rather than the NVIDIA card. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Windows 10, you can take advantage of the Graphics Settings page within Settings -> System -> Display to force a particular graphics card.

[image]

Once you navigate to Graphics Settings (far bottom), you can choose Desktop app as the type and browse for the particular executable you want to set the preference for.

[image]

By default, Windows 10 will set any newly configured programs to "Let Windows Decide". You can easily override this by clicking the program, clicking Options, and then choosing High Performance.

[image]

Once this is completed, you should see something like the below:
[image]

Comment: +1 Nice solution.